# Object type Manipulation Issue

Tags: plsql

I have a seemingly harmless piece of code that is as below.

```
CREATE TYPE rec_type AS object (
  storename VARCHAR2(50),
  storecode VARCHAR2(50),
  --enters number,
  --exits number,
  log_ts    DATE,
  opentime  VARCHAR2(50),
  closetime VARCHAR2(50),
  ttotals   VARCHAR2(50) );

/

CREATE TYPE t_tab
  IS TABLE OF rec_type;

/

CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Dx_proc_dly_charmingcharlie (
  p_ce_id            IN NUMBER,
  p_strt_dt          IN DATE,
  p_end_dt           IN DATE,
  p_date_format      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'mm/dd/yy',
  p_time_format      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'hh24miss',
  p_store_format     IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
  p_file_sep         IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',',
  p_total_type       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'B',
  p_act_imp_ind_reqd IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'N')
AS
  ltotals VARCHAR2(100);
  lstr    VARCHAR(500);
  --type t_tab is table of rec_type;
  tt_tab  t_tab := T_tab();
  CURSOR cce IS
    SELECT ce_id,
           url_adr user_store_code
    FROM   tce
    WHERE  ce_id = p_ce_id
           AND hist_ctrl = 0
           AND cmpl_ind = 'Y'
           AND end_ind = 'N'
           AND ce_fnct_typ_id IN ( 1, 2, 6 )
    UNION
    SELECT a.ce_id,
           a.url_adr user_store_code
    FROM   tce a,
           tce_rlt b
    WHERE  b.ce_prn_id = p_ce_id
           AND b.ce_dpn_id = a.ce_id
           AND b.hist_ctrl = 0
           AND a.hist_ctrl = 0
           AND a.cmpl_ind = 'Y'
           AND a.end_ind = 'N'
           AND a.ce_fnct_typ_id IN ( 1, 2, 6 )
           AND b.cmpl_ind = 'Y'
           AND b.end_ind = 'N';
  CURSOR ctrf(
    p_ce_id NUMBER) IS
    SELECT a.url_adr                         StoreName,
           Rfg_get_cust_id_gen(a.url_adr)    Storecode,
           SUM(b.total_enters)               enters,
           SUM(b.total_exits)                exits,
           b.log_ts                          log_ts,
           To_char(b.day_strt_ts, 'hh24:mi') opentime,
           To_char(b.day_end_ts, 'hh24:mi')  closetime
    FROM   tce a,
           mv_tmp_daily_traffic b,
           v_ce_tmp c
    WHERE  c.ce_id = a.ce_id
           AND b.tmp_id = c.tmp_id
           AND a.ce_id = p_ce_id
           AND b.log_ts >= p_strt_dt
           AND b.log_ts <= p_end_dt
    GROUP  BY a.url_adr,
              Rfg_get_cust_id_gen(a.url_adr),
              To_char(b.log_ts, 'YYYY/MM/DD'),
              b.log_ts,
              To_char(b.day_strt_ts, 'hh24:mi'),
              To_char(b.day_end_ts, 'hh24:mi')
    ORDER  BY 1,
              2,
              5;
BEGIN
    FOR c IN cce LOOP
        FOR t IN ctrf(c.ce_id) LOOP
            lTotals := CASE p_total_type
                         WHEN 'B' THEN To_char(t.enters)
                                       || ','
                                       || To_char(t.exits)
                         WHEN 'E' THEN To_char(t.enters)
                         ELSE To_char(t.exits)
                       END;

            tt_tab.extend;


Tt_tab(tt_tab.last) :=
Rec_type(t.storename, t.storecode, t.log_ts, t.opentime, t.closetime, lTotals);

lStr := CASE p_total_type
          WHEN 'B' THEN
          'Store ID|Store Name|Date|Open Time|Close Time|Traffic In|Traffic Out'
          WHEN 'E' THEN
          'Store ID|Store Name|Date|Open Time|Close Time|Traffic In'
          ELSE 'Store ID|Store Name|Date|Open Time|Close Time|Traffic Out'
        END;

dbms_output.Put_line(lStr);
--dbms_output.put_line(t.Storecode||p_file_sep||t.StoreName||p_file_sep||to_char(t.log_ts,p_date_format)||p_file_sep||t.opentime||p_file_sep||t.closetime||lTotals);
END LOOP;
END LOOP;


FOR rec IN 1..tt_tab.count LOOP
    dbms_output.Put_line(Tt_tab(rec).Storecode
                         ||p_file_sep
                         ||Tt_tab(rec).StoreName
                         ||p_file_sep
                         || Tt_tab(rec).log_ts
                         ||p_file_sep
                         ||Tt_tab(rec).opentime
                         ||p_file_sep
                         ||Tt_tab(rec).closetime
                         ||p_file_sep
                         || Tt_tab(rec).lTotals);
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
             Raise_application_error(-20001, Substr(SQLERRM, 1, 100));
END;

/
```

This is giving the error

```
84/206         PLS-00302: component 'LTOTALS' must be declared   
84/2           PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Although I have declared the variable "LTOTALS" as global..   Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I see this in your code:

```
tt_tab(rec).lTotals
```

but there is no attribute `lTotals` in record type `rec_type`, only `tTotals`.

Comment: Thank you very much . It complies now.But it's throwing out the error 
PL/SQL numeric or value error.character to number conversion error at run time.
Where should I look for it??

Comment: Remove this redundant code and you may get a better indication from Oracle of where the error really is: `EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
             Raise_application_error(-20001, Substr(SQLERRM, 1, 100));`

Comment: The error is said to be generated in line 

for  rec in  1..tt_tab.count loop